# What is causing this GCP GAE [RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED] quota error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gae-quotas

When deploying to GCP App Engine (Flexible) I'm getting a `[RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED]` error that I can't seem to make sense of.

```
The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota.
```

Full error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [8] Flex operation projects/project/regions/europe-west3/operations/8824354e-eaaf-45a6-9760-47167218e043 error [RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-12-27T11:41:01.342Z18480.xj.2: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas for more information on GCE resources
```

Could this be related to my `app.yaml` configuration?

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 1.4
  disk_size_gb: 10
network:
  name: default
liveness_check:
  path: "/liveness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  initial_delay_sec: 300
readiness_check:
  path: "/readiness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 15
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
  target_concurrent_requests: 100
```

If not, then what could it be related to?

Checking the [quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) page shows that all quotas seem to be within limits.

Comment: I tried redeploying with `memory_gb: 4` and I get the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) the parameter 'max_num_instances', The maximum number of instances in your project should be 8 by default where I can see you are using 15. I would like to suggest you to increase the [quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) limit for your project will solve the issue.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much. I've instead lowered my `max_num_instances` to `8` to match the default quota limit. Checking now to see if that solves the issue

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you so much