# ERROR: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I decided to use App Engine Flexible. But I am getting this error:

```
The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas for more information on GCE resources
```

I have a billing account connected and have $ 300 in credit.

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
service: server
env: flex

network:
  session_affinity: true

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

I've been trying to figure out how to fix this for a whole day now :(
Does anyone understand why this is so?

Comment: can you please share your app.yaml? how many min instances are you setting?

Comment: Follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/65466919/11866104, might be helpful

Comment: @Chris32 
I have pinned the yaml app in the question

Comment: @Mahboob 
Yes, apparently this is the answer to my question. Thanks, I'll try now

Comment: @adelnorberg I hope this solve the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is causing this GCP GAE \[RESOURCE\_EXHAUSTED\] quota error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466222/what-is-causing-this-gcp-gae-resource-exhausted-quota-error)

Comment: @Mahboob, thanks a lot.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @mahboob, the answer for this question is as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466222/what-is-causing-this-gcp-gae-resource-exhausted-quota-error)

> As per the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) the parameter 'max_num_instances', The maximum number of instances in your project should be 8 by default where I can see you are using 15. I would like to suggest you to increase the [quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) limit for your project will solve the issue.

Comment: many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get through the deployment and don't care scaling, the following might help.

1. try to delete all versions and instances as many as possible, and remember to repeat deletion multiple times because deletion might fail.
2. in your app.yaml, limit the instance number to just 1 instance, and then try to deploy again.

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```