# App Engine Flex deploy command returns "The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

Running `gcloud app deploy` returns:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                             
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [8] Flex operation 
projects/cervical-cell/regions/europe-west1/operations/a3a34181-9195-4c43-b015-9f911699f5f0 error 
[RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2021-04-08T16:17:56.018Z9043.wa.1: 
The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. 
Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas for more information on GCE resources
```

Comment: Try setting the max number of instances on your app.yaml below the quota limit. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65466919/7031308

Comment: thanks, i solve problem with your solution when setted max and min number of instances it worked very well