# How to deploy a java project on Google cloud Platform from eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Could someone please mention the exact steps needed to deploy a spring project to GCP.

I tried doing it through eclipse by changing it to a JAR file and pressing Deploy to appengine flexible such as:

[image: the deploy option]

but an error occurred which was:

[image: Error Image]

The error was:

```
(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [8] Flex operation projects/interestcalculation/regions/asia-southeast2/operations/e1ad81d6-c153-4a64-ab95-d5b8c544c7c8 error [RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2021-07-27T07:24:30.414Z5288.fk.0: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas for more information on GCE resources
```

This is my app.yaml file:
[image: app.yaml file img]

Please Help, Thank You!

Comment: Can you share you app.yaml file if you deploy on App Engine? Can you also tell us if you have a linked billing account to your project? Finally, is App Engine flex your final choice or are you open to different options? If so, what are your app constraints?

Comment: I've added the app.yaml file above and I believe I have linked my billing account to my project. I am open to other options, I have two APIs and I need it to be called using the scheduler so that it can fetch data and display on webpage. @guillaumeblaquire

Comment: In which region is set up your App Engine service? Do you have other Comput Engine instances in your project? did you check the quota page to understand where is the issue?

Comment: @dev can you try to deploy your app in another region? Rarely App Engine doesn't have enough resources to allow VM deployment for Flex instances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is causing this GCP GAE \[RESOURCE\_EXHAUSTED\] quota error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466222/what-is-causing-this-gcp-gae-resource-exhausted-quota-error)

Comment: thanks guys! Now I'm getting another error when I open the webpage. It says "Error: Not Found" not sure why though

Answer (score 1):

Based on @guillaumeblaquiere, @FerreginaMasalo comments, to mitigate the error in App Engine, you can do the following:

- As the error refers to a specific region, try deploying your app in another one as there might be not enough resources to allow VM deployment in the region you selected.
- Verify your [quota](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas).
- Request the [quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) if it's necessary.